# How to assert array in array?

Tags: javascript, json, testing, postman, assertion

Can somebody please help me to assert array in array in postman ?

I have this peace of code:

```
"documents": [
        {
            "fileName": "file01_guid.pdf",
            "documentType": "document",
            "parentFiles": [
                "file01.pdf"
            ]
        },
        {
            "fileName": "file02_guid.pdf",
            "documentType": "document",
            "parentFiles": [
                "file01.pdf"
            ]
        }
```

I need to assert the "ParentFiles" array using this method:

```
var array = [];
var range = (json_response.data.documents).length

for (var i = 0; i < range; i++)

{
 var file = json_response.data.documents[i].fileName
 var type = json_response.data.documents[i].documentType;

 array.push(file)
 array.push(type)
}
```

So I could write this kind of test:

```
{
    pm.expect(array).to.include("file01.pdf", "file01.pdf");
});
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: what you want to assert ? why are you pushind document type also ?

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: I want to assert the parentFiles array using "include" function, like I've described it in my post. I'm stuck a little

Comment: you want to assert parentFile array of each object or you want to assert the new array with some array

Comment: If there are two ways on how to approach my goal then - I want to know both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can verify if `"file01.pdf"` exists by simply filtering and checking the length. You can also build your `array` more efficiently by reducing.

```js
const json_response = {
  "data": {
    "documents": [{
      "fileName": "file01_guid.pdf",
      "documentType": "document",
      "parentFiles": ["file01.pdf"]
    }, {
      "fileName": "file02_guid.pdf",
      "documentType": "document",
      "parentFiles": ["file01.pdf"]
    }]
  }
};

const array = json_response.data.documents.reduce((acc, doc) => {
  const { fileName, documentType, parentFiles: [ pfName ] } = doc;
  return [ ...acc, fileName, documentType, pfName ];
}, []);

console.log(array);

// Exactly two instances of "file01.pdf" exist.
console.log(array.filter(val => val === "file01.pdf").length === 2);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

If you just want to compare the arrays, you can try the following:

```js
const json_response = {
  "data": {
    "documents": [{
      "fileName": "file01_guid.pdf",
      "documentType": "document",
      "parentFiles": ["file01.pdf"]
    }, {
      "fileName": "file02_guid.pdf",
      "documentType": "document",
      "parentFiles": ["file01.pdf"]
    }]
  }
};

const allEqual = json_response.data.documents
  .every(({ parentFiles: [ filename ] }) => filename === "file01.pdf");

console.log(allEqual);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: why can't you just use lodash ?

Comment: @PDHide because JavaScript has evolved and dependencies are extra overhead.

Comment: @PDHide The code works in NodeJS too, it is not DOM-manipulation (or dependent) code.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl In the end I've decided to use your method:

`const array = json_response.data.documents.reduce((acc, doc) => {
  const { fileName, documentType, parentFiles: [ pfName ] } = doc;
  return [ ...acc, fileName, documentType, pfName ];
}, []);`

Because I the response, the documents can be different. I've studied your method and it totally fits to my needs.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**you can loop using foreach and compare the values**

```
//store expected files in order
array=["file01.pdf","file01.pdf"]

//now forEach on each element
json_response.data.documents.forEach( (elem,index,arr)=>{
pm.expect(elem.parentFiles[0]).to.be.eql(array[index])
})
```

**If you just want to compare two arrays then:**

```
pm.expect(_.isEqual(array,array2)).to.be.true
```

lodash isEqual can be used to compare two object like arrays

Comment: I have not understood your "loop" option. When I've tried:

`pm.test('parentFiles equal "BR_21080_file18.pdf"', function()

    {
        array=["file01.pdf","file01.pdf"]

        pm.response.json().documents.forEach( (elem,index,arr)=>{
        pm.expect(elem.parentFiles[0]).to.be.eql(array[index])
    })});`

I've received "parentFiles equal "file18.pdf" | TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined"

Comment: is the updated  code json_response.data.documents